# Can I say, "Choose your true, new flavour"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

What the phrase is expressing is, "Choose what's truly your favourite flavour".

Can I say, "Choose your true, new flavour"?

Comment: What makes you think you can **not**? Where exactly does it ring incorrect to you? So we can guess what you expect in answer.

Comment: Semantically, the sentence may be inappropriate -- grammatically, it seems perfect to me.

Comment: Using "true" instead of "truly" changes the meaning of the sentence and doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gramatically that's correct, but always think if the opposite makes sense.

> Choose your false, old flavour

The *true* is absolutely unclear as to what it means - what does it mean a flavor is true? It's nowhere near implying "truly favorite". It could be interpreted as "real flavor of X" instead of an artificial substitute maybe, but that's stretching it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little confusing, because "new" doesn't appear in your definition of "What the phrase is expressing". I'm going to assume that what you meant to say was "Choose what's truly your favourite *new* flavour."

"Choose your true, new flavour" won't work.

In the first place, "true, new flavour", with the comma, means in English syntax

> Choose your flavour which is true *and* new.

Without the comma it's still not what you want: that means

> Choose your new flavour which is true.

Your fundamental problem is that the only word your catchphrase supplies which carries any (forgive me) flavour of "favourite" is *your*. **That** is what, according to your definition, you want *true* to modify, and you express that this way:

> Choose the new flavour which is truly yours.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to change the sentence to, "Choose your new flavour favourite."

Comment: It feels as though forcing _true_ into such a short sentence was the problem.

Comment: @WarrenvanRooyen   I think so. It's easy to get seduced by musical effects; but as Lewis Carroll says, "Take care of the sense and the sounds will take care of themselves."

Comment: Seduced by musical effects?